# Move a button out of the screen

Tags: java, android

When the margin of a button become more than the resolution of the screen, the button stops growing, is there any workaround ?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        Thread th = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) testButton
                        .getLayoutParams();
                params.topMargin += 10;
                params.leftMargin += 10;
                testButton.setLayoutParams(params);
                handler.postDelayed(this,100);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(th,100);
    }
```

Comment: You mean the button stops growing? Can you post `activity_main.xml`. It will help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a translate animation to do this. Try something like this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int widthScreen = display.getWidth();

Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, widthScreen ,0, widthScreen);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
testButton.startAnimation(animation);
testButton.setVisibility(0);
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i wont to know if there is any way to do that only with margins :)

Comment: Well, i guess that you can use my two first lines, and check when your leftMargin become bigger than widthScreen. If yes, stop your loop.

Comment: Is there a way to draw part of the button background to looks like the button go out side of the screen ?

Comment: I think you can do this by puting your Button alone in a LinearLayout, and then changing the margin of the layout instead of the button.
Let me know.

Comment: I make simple game with many balloons that move around the screen. I use RelativeLayout to achieve this so i can't use alone button in a linearLayout :)